# how to use data from child activity in MainActivity and use it as parameter in other methods

Tags: java, android

I want to send data from EditText in child activity to parent activity (MainActivity) and use it as a string parameter (URL) in other methods

Already I am able to send this using intent and extras, also I added textview in method to see if it works, but finally, this textview will be deleted, but I can't use it in other methods

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataSendToActivity {

    ImageView bg_state;
    Button btn_rl; 
    TextView txt_network;
    String url;
    String my_url;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bg_state = findViewById(R.id.bg_status);
        txt_network = findViewById(R.id.txt_network);

        Toolbar toolbar= findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tv=findViewById(R.id.tV);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                    bg_state.setImageResource(R.drawable.background);
                    txt_network.setText("");
                }else{
                    bg_state.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_on);
                    txt_network.setText("Cound not connect to the server");
                }

                updateStatus();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
            }
        }, 5000);  //the time is in miliseconds



        btn_rl = findViewById(R.id.sw_1);
        btn_rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url_rl = my_url+"room_light";
                SelectTask task = new SelectTask(url_rl);
                task.execute();
                updateStatus();
            }
        });

      String url_rl = url+"bed_light";
                SelectTask task = new SelectTask(url_rl);
                task.execute();
                updateStatus();
            }
        });*/

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id==R.id.conf){
            Intent intent_conf = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Configuration.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent_conf,1);
            return false;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==1){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                url=data.getStringExtra("url");
                my_url="http://"+url;
                tv.setText(my_url);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(String str) {
        updateButtonStatus(str);
    }

    private void updateStatus(){
        String url_rl = my_url+"status";
        StatusTask task = new StatusTask(url_rl, this);
        task.execute();
    }

    //Function for updating Button Status
    private void updateButtonStatus(String jsonStrings){
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStrings);

            String room_light = json.getString("rl");

            if(room_light.equals("1")){
                btn_rl.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.plug_90off);
            }else{
                btn_rl.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.plug_90on);
            }
        .setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.power_off);
            }


        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**childactivity**

```
public class Configuration extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String new_url;
    EditText ip_text;
    Button sub_btn;
    String a;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);

        Toolbar tool = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(tool);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if(actionBar!=null){
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }


        findViewById(R.id.wifi_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToUrl("https://192.168.4.1");
            }
        });

        ip_text = findViewById(R.id.ip_text);
        sub_btn= findViewById(R.id.sub_btn);

        sub_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Configuration.this,MainActivity.class);
                new_url=ip_text.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("url",new_url);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

What I need is that if I write in Configuration class for example *192.168.xx.xx* In mainactivity my_url will be *my_url="https://192.168/* and it will be able to use in other methods as a parameter (for example in `btn_rl.setOnClickListener`).

Comment: What's the problem here? It seems that you got what you need already.

Comment: No, i am only able to show it in textview doing it in onActivityResult, but what I need is that i will be able to use it in btn_rl.setOnClickListener to update the status

Comment: But i see you are using `String url_rl = my_url+"room_light";` in there, where `my_url` is set in the previous listener.

Comment: yes, i wonder if it will work but unfortunatelly its null then

Comment: It's probably null because you haven't set it up

Comment: What you mean by that? What i should do then?

Comment: What that code is doing is to set up that `my_url` variable in the second activity. So you need to set it up before you can use it at `btn_rl`

Comment: Using (mainActivity) ```this.startActivityForResult(intent, 45454)``` set the result (ChildActivity) ```setResult(RESULT_OK, bundleDataToGetlatter)``` and get the result at ```onActivityResult``` at MainActivity, it have request code equals the one you set from startActivityForResult (in this case 45454) and the Bundle you set at ChildActivity

Comment: Okay, so I tried to use setResult(RESULT_OK, new_url) instead of my intent, but this method doesnt deall with that. Also tried to set textview not in onActivityResult but in onCreate and nothing happens, so that means that url that i send form child to Main is only available in onActivityResult. Maybe there is different method to use in that case where I need to use that data in onCreate and one other method